# 'wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)' in simple Ruby SSL client

Tags: ruby, ssl

I am writing a simple SSL client for pentester lab bootcamp module 4. I enabled SSL for the virtualhost and enabled the module. The SSL client is written in Ruby and when running the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
6: from 4-http_ssl.rb:8:in <main>
5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:1458:in request
4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in start
3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in do_start
2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:985:in connect
1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in ssl_socket_connect
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in connect_nonblock: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 
state=error: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

Here is my script

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

http = Net::HTTP.new("vulnerable", 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

response = http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("/"))
response.code
response.body
response.status
```

Can someone throw me a line here? I've checked the example and the server files but can't find the error. This seems like shouldn't be much trouble. Am I missing some configuration steps?

As pointed out by Steffen Ullrich, I tried to run

```
openssl> s_client
```

and got the following output:

```
Openssl> s_client -connect vulnerable:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140093579711616:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 293 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
error in s_client
```

What steps should I follow? I understand the server is not accepting SSL connections because of missing CA certificates, how can I fix this I know I can create a custom CA certificate for my ssl client any leads on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a common error when the server does not actually support SSL. Try tools like `openssl s_client` to check the server with a known good client before you look for the bug in your own client.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, I updated the post with the output from s_client. What should I do now? I don't really understand what exactly is failing.

Comment: Please have a look t how s_client should be used. You have to actually specify where it should connect to, i.e. `openssl s_client -connect host:port`.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I ran it properly this time and got the output above. I understand this meas what I am missing is a CA certificate for my ssl client right? Or is it for the server. Is there a way to skip the verification for a certificate?

Comment: This is not related to certificate validation. In fact, no certificate is there too validate since the server seems to respond with something which is not even TLS. Thus, it is likely an improperly setup server, like a server doing plain HTTP on a port where HTTPS is expected.

Comment: I see, I will check my server setup. Thank you

Comment: I checked my configuration and it seems to be ok, how can I check uf my server is doing ssl instead of plain http? Pardon my ignorance I am pretty new to this

Comment: *"how can I check uf my server is doing ssl instead of plain http?"* - point your browser at `https://vulnerable`. If it works it should work with ruby too. If not your server setup is likely broken.

Comment: It is broken. Is it too much to ask you to guide me through a setup verification? I followed the guides and disabled tls versions and ciphers and other questions I've checked and followed have provided no results

Comment: Please ask a new question about your broken server setup which all details needed, i.e. what kind of server, version, exact configuration, any error messages you have in the logs etc.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your guidence

Comment: So NASA also has a broken server setup? https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/curiosity_selfie.jpg