# Graphql-Client ruby OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphqlclient

I am trying to test if I can connect to a graphql API from a `rails` backend by using `graphql-client` with the following code:

```
require "graphql/client"
require "graphql/client/http"

HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("https://x.x.x.x:3100/graphql") 

Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)

Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema, execute: HTTP)
```

but I get the following error:

```
    9: from db/seeds.rb:14:in `<main>'
    8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.16.0/lib/graphql/client.rb:61:in `load_schema'
    7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.16.0/lib/graphql/client.rb:77:in `dump_schema'
    6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/graphql-client-0.16.0/lib/graphql/client/http.rb:73:in `execute'
    5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:1470:in `request'
    4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:919:in `start'
    3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:930:in `do_start'
    2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:996:in `connect'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

`SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

I have no idea how to get that solved as when I look that error up it is always in different situation than mine.

Comment: Do you know what system your GraphQL server is running on (is it localhost?) and can you let us know which operating system you're running your client on?

Comment: I am running the server as well, is a [cardano-graphql](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql) running with Hasura. Is running on dell Precision Tower with  Ubuntu latest version.
I am trying to query that machine from a MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016) with BigSur Version 11.0.1 (20B50).
My network is behind a BT router which portforwards to the Ubuntu machine for port :3100.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991618/ it looks like your server is not running in https mode, your URL is an "https" url, are you sure this is secured?